# ServiceStack - Autoquery & Swapping Client Templates

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor, servicestack-autoquery

Using ServiceStack's Autoquery I have a simple Request DTO defined (example below). I would like to swap templates (Layouts) to use a different Razor layout (as per the SS templates swap documentation [here](http://docs.servicestack.net/view-and-template-selection))?

Example of Request DTO:

```
Route("/customers", "GET")]
public class QueryCustomers : QueryDb<FindFilesResponse>
{

}
```

Example  of Layouts:
 _Layout.cshtml and _PrintFriendly.cshtml templates

For above query I would like to swap layouts at the client level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the [ClientCanSwapTemplatesAttribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/ClientCanSwapTemplatesAttribute.cs) does is populate the `IRequest.Items` dictionary from the HTTP Request params:

```
public class ClientCanSwapTemplatesAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute
{
    public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        req.Items["View"] = req.GetParam("View");
        req.Items["Template"] = req.GetParam("Template");
    }
}
```

So you could choose to do this in a [Request Filter](http://docs.servicestack.net/request-and-response-filters#typed-request-filters), e.g:

```
RegisterTypedRequestFilter<QueryCustomers>((req, res, dto) =>
{
    req.Items["View"] = req.GetParam("View");
    req.Items["Template"] = req.GetParam("Template");
});
```

Alternatively in order to be able to use [Filter Attributes](http://docs.servicestack.net/filter-attributes) on AutoQuery Services since they're implementation is auto-generated is to create a [Custom AutoQuery implementation](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#custom-autoquery-implementations), e.g:

```
[ClientCanSwapTemplates]
public class MyQueryServices : Service
{
    public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }

    //Override with custom implementation
    public object Any(QueryCustomers query)
    {
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(query, base.Request);
        return AutoQuery.Execute(request, q);
    }
}
```

Whilst Filter attributes would also work when annotated on the Request DTO, i,e:

```
[ClientCanSwapTemplates]
[Route("/customers", "GET")]
public class QueryCustomers { ... }
```

They're usage is discouraged because they would add dependencies to your Service Model. But another solution could be to [add Attributes dynamically](http://docs.servicestack.net/routing#dynamically-adding-route-attributes) in your AppHost constructor, e,g:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() 
    { 
        typeof(QueryCustomers)
            .AddAttributes(new ClientCanSwapTemplatesAttribute());
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container) { ... }
}
```